# Topological homogeneity of the Hilbert cube

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

The Hilbert cube $Q = [-1,1]^\mathbb{N}$ is topologically homogeneous. That is, for each $x,y \in Q$, there is a homeomorphism $f: Q \to Q$ such that $f(x) = y$. I’m looking at the proof of this fact in *Selected Topics in Infinite-Dimensional Topology*, Chapter 3, Section 4, and having some trouble with a particular step. I’ll reproduce the relevant information below.

Let $I = [-1,1]$, and let $p_n: Q \to I$ denote the $n$-th coordinate map. Let Auth$(X)$ denote the space of homeomorphisms $X \to X$. On $Q$ we use the metric
$$d(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}|p_n(x) - p_n(y)|.$$
And on Auth$(Q)$ we use the metric
$$D(F,G) = \sup_{x \in Q} d(F(x), G(x)) + \sup_{x \in Q} d(F^{-1}(x), G^{-1}(x)).$$

The authors need to show (in the proof of lemma 4.3) that for every $z \in Q$ with $|p_n(z)| = 1$, and every $\epsilon$ such that $1 > \epsilon > 0$, there is an $F \in \text{Auth}(Q)$ such that $d(F,\text{Id}) < \epsilon$ and $|p_n(F(z))| < 1$. To do this, they define an automorphism $f \in \text{Auth}(I^2)$, pick $m > n$ so that $2^{-m} < \epsilon/8$ and define $F$ by
$$
(p_n(F(x)), p_m(F(x)) = f(p_n(x), p_m(x))
$$
$$p_i(F(x)) = p_i(x) \text{ for } i \notin \{n,m\}.$$

The problem is that their definition of $f$ appears to have a typo, and I can't figure out what the definition ought to be. In the book they write

> Let $a,b,c,d \in I^2$ be the points $a = (-1,1), b = (1,1), a' = (1-\epsilon/6,1), b' = (1-\epsilon/6,1)$. Let $f \in \text{Auth}(I^2)$ such that
> $$
> f([a;b]) = [a';b'],\quad f(-x,-y) = -(x,y), \quad f(x,y) = (x,y) \text{ if }|x| < 1-\epsilon/4.
> $$

Above $[x;y]$ denotes the closed line segment connecting $x$ and $y$. Can anyone see what definition of $f$ makes this argument work?

Comment: Why do you think there's a typo? If I recall correctly, this automorphism is a bit hard to define precisely, and what they probably are doing here is only define what it should satisfy, leaving it a bit to the reader to convince themselves that such $f$ really exists.

Comment: The big problem is that $a’ = b’$, so $f$ is taking a line segment to a point, meaning $f$ can’t be an automorphism.  (Also, the quoted section mentions $a,b,c,d$ but then defines $a,b,a’,b’$. Not a huge deal obviously.)

Comment: I guessed they may have meant $a’ = (-1+\epsilon/6, 1)$ and $b’ = (1-\epsilon/6,1)$, but I wasn’t able to make it work assuming that. Maybe I should try it again…

Comment: Yes, that's what they meant. Still, you'll have trouble trying to define such automorphism. You can try to check [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4404309/existence-of-a-homeomorphism-of-an-n-dimensional-cube). It's a similar construction and I've asked it because I also was struggling with the proof of homogenity of the Hilbert cube

Comment: If you take $a' = (-1+\epsilon/6,1)$, where doyou  get a problem?

Comment: I think I've got it at this point, I went ahead and wrote an answer. Thank you Jakobian and Paul!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going to answer my own question since I believe I figured this out. In the book, it should be $a' = (-1  + \epsilon/6, 1)$.

The concept here is that you make very little change in the $x$-coordinate (which corresponds to the $n$-th coordinate for the Hilbert cube), but potentially a large change in the $y$-coordinate (corresponding to the $m$-th coordinate of the Hilbert cube). Because you can make $m$ as big as you want, changes in the $y$-coordinate are negligible in the metric. You are taking the left and right side of the square into the top of the square. I'm attaching an exaggerated sketch below to demonstrate the idea.

[image: Sketch of the definition of f]